# Error 201: User not visible in facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

When the app may be to post for an user in the wall of your friends...

```
Error 201: User not visible in facebook api
```

Please if any people can explain me about this error, and its causes. I don't know mouch about facebook api, but I understand that a post publication by an application integrated with facebook can publish unlimited post for any user.

Why a user is not visible in facebook api???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems it's a bug: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=11471
Many people report this, I also encountered this problem today...

Comment: Thanks, it ocured when a facebook profile is added to system DB but the profile owner is not added the applicaon in your facebook profile and you security is blocked for unknow applications

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, it ocured when a facebook profile is added to system DB but the profile owner is not added the applicaon in your facebook profile and you security is blocked for unknow applications