# Facebook authentication error: authorize#error_code=210&error_msg=User%20not%20visible

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error 201: User not visible in facebook api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703365/error-201-user-not-visible-in-facebook-api)

I am trying to authenticate my application using Facebook SDK. It works fine for most of the users but for some users it will show the following users

authorize#error_code=210&error_msg=User%20not%20visible

Could you please help if you have any suggestions?

Comment: This error is returned when the posting user A does not have sufficient permission to post on User B's wall. This would be a privacy setting by user B and outside the control of User A or your app

Comment: Check if your app has any user restrictions set in the App Dashboard. Ensure the user-ids are not subject to the restrictions you have set.

Check if FB has placed any restrictions on your app (eg. Mobile Web integration is blocked by FB).  If so, resolve them.

Set the "iPhone App Store ID" in the App Dashboard.  You can enter a fake one like 123456, for testing/development.  This is not an exact dupe because this is an issue in the auth flow with the fb ios-sdk (other stackoverflow question is about a post operation).  See also:  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/113311158833267

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the particular user has disabled posting on his wall or action you want to perform.

For example, i tried posting on a user's wall from my app, but since the user had disabled wall posts on his timeline, i got the same error.

Unfortunately, there's only solution for it, ask the user to allow wall posts on his timeline!